# Is there any difference between javascript engine used in node and crome browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have run following code in both crome broswer console and thru node engine, got different result

code:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 10;

foo();
```

output in Crome browser: 10

and when I saved above code in main.js file run below command

node main.js

output: undefined

Answer (score 1):

`this` is scoped to the window object in browsers. NodeJS doesn't have a window object, it has a `global` which is different. So `var a = 10` is hoisted up, and `this.a` accesses it.

If you `console.log(this)` in your function, you'll see:

```
Window {stop: function, open: function, alert: function, confirm: function, prompt: function…}
```

`this` isn't scoped to `foo`, it's scoped to `window`

Note that if you declared `this.a` inside foo, your results would be different.

```
function foo() {
    this.a = 4;
    console.log(this.a); //now logs 4 instead of 10
}
```